# How to sed to capture the rightmost string?

Tags: regex, bash, awk, sed

I have different environments. In each environment logs are located in different path. e.g.:

```
/u01/../etc/apps/../def-20150626044921.log 
/u01/log02/../etc/apps/../mno-20150626071656.log 
/u02/../etc/apps/../xyz-20150626044921.log
```

I am trying to grab the rightmost digits just before .log and display them in `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS` format.

Using these in different combinations I could get the result individually. e.g.:

```
sed "s/01//"; 
sed "s/[^0-9]*//g"; 
sed "s/(.{4})(.{2})(.{2})/\1-\2-\3 /", 
sed "s/(.{10})(.{3})(.{2})/\1 \2:\3:/";
```

My requirement is to add the command in a script. However, I'm unable get the results when the path is different. Like if instead of `u01`, it's `u02` the command doesn't work.

Basically I just need to capture the `YYYYMMDDHHMMSS` before .log and remove everything else. Is there a way to make the command dynamic so it is independent of the log path and should not matter where the logs are located, it will always show the date and time in the desired format.

Thanks for looking at the question...!!

Comment: I guess you do not want to take a substring like `${var:(-18):14}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
sed 's/.*\([0-9]\{4\}\)\([0-9]\{2\}\)\([0-9]\{2\}\)\([0-9]\{2\}\)\([0-9]\{2\}\)\([0-9]\{2\}\).log$/\1-\2-\3 \4:\5:\6/' infile
```

Explanation:

- `.*` matches everything up until the first digit, which we don't capture cause we don't need it.
- `\([0-9]\{4\}\)` captures the year
- the following 5 occurrences of `\([0-9]\{2\}\)` capture the month, day, hour, minute and second.
- `.log$` after the number we match the file extension and the end of the line, which we again don't capture cause we don't need it.
- then we sub them for with the desired format `\1-\2-\3 \4:\5`

Comment: I would have changed `.log` to `\.log$`... But this answer is correct... Also, for better readability, you can add another line by changing `sed` to `sed -i` & dropping the `\\` characters...

Comment: Yes I was just doing that while explaining! Thanks for the input though @anishsane!

Answer (score 3):

You can use `bash` parameter substitution like this without starting `sed`:

```
x="/u02/../etc/apps/../xyz-20150626044921.log"
d1=${x%.log}    # strip ".log"
d2=${d1##*-}    # strip everything up to dash

echo $d2
20150626044921
```

Examples and details are [here](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html).

Comment: Then you can use `date -d"$d2" "+ <format>"` for this.

Comment: @ShellFish You are probably right, I was focussing on the sentence `Basically I just need to capture the YYYYMMDDHHMMSS before .log and remove everything else`. I'll leave it as a possible option and folks can take their pick:-)

Comment: Of course, the shell substitution is always a great way to do it, so fast. Fedorqui made a real good point to format it later with `date`. If you'd include that in your answer, it would definitely be the better of the two answers!

Comment: By the way, I tend to give the bash guide reference (http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html in this case), since apparently tldp.org has errors on a regular basis.

Comment: @fedorqui For me it gives `date: invalid date ‘20150626044921’` error on writing `date -d"$d2"`

Comment: @RakholiyaJenish uhms, I see. The minimal change to get something that works is `date -d"20150626 04:49:21"`. So splitting after 8th character, plus adding `:` in between  the rest of pairs.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ sed -r 's/.*(....)(..)(..)(..)(..)(..)\.log$/\1-\2-\3 \4:\5:\6/' file
2015-06-26 04:49:21
2015-06-26 07:16:56
2015-06-26 04:49:21
```

or with GNU awk for gensub():

```
$ gawk '{print gensub(/.*(....)(..)(..)(..)(..)(..)\.log$/,"\\1-\\2-\\3 \\4:\\5:\\6","")}' file
2015-06-26 04:49:21
2015-06-26 07:16:56
2015-06-26 04:49:21
```

or again with GNU awk, this time for the third arg to match():

```
$ gawk 'match($0,/(....)(..)(..)(..)(..)(..)\.log$/,a){print a[1]"-"a[2]"-"a[3]" "a[4]":"a[5]":"a[6]}' file
2015-06-26 04:49:21
2015-06-26 07:16:56
2015-06-26 04:49:21
```

That last is particularly useful if you want to do anything additional with the parts of the date/time you have isolated from the input (e.g. add or subtract some value from or otherwise modify any/all of them) since it stores then in an array (`a[]`), unlike the first gawk script and the sed script which just output a modified version of the input string. For example:

```
$ echo "20150607120500" | gawk 'match($0,/(....)(..)(..)(..)(..)(..)/,a){time=a[4]":"a[5]":"a[6]; if (time=="12:00:00") time="noon"; print a[1]"-"a[2]"-"a[3], time}'
2015-06-07 12:05:00

$ echo "20150607120000" | gawk 'match($0,/(....)(..)(..)(..)(..)(..)/,a){time=a[4]":"a[5]":"a[6]; if (time=="12:00:00") time="noon"; print a[1]"-"a[2]"-"a[3], time}'
2015-06-07 noon
```

Comment: As always, great answer in awk.

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk`:

```
awk -F '[-\.]' '{a=$(NF-1); print substr(a,1,4) "-" substr(a,5,2) "-" substr(a,7,2) " " substr(a,9,2) ":" substr(a,11,2) ":" substr(a,13,2);}' filename
```

`substr(a,i,j)` will take return the substring from `a`, starting at index `i` and of length `j`.

I think it is simple to understand.

Comment: Nice, always happy to see someone tackle a problem with [tag:awk]. Maybe just add a wee bit more clarification?

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F'[-.]' '{sub(/20150626/,"2015-06-26 ",$6)sub(/ 0./,"&:",$6)sub(/..$/,":&",$6);print $6}' file

2015-06-26 04:49:21
2015-06-26 07:16:56
2015-06-26 04:49:21
```